# What is the best practice for versioning Android intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Let say I wrote an app that would respond to a particular custom intent but the behaviour surrounding that intent has changed from one app version to another.

Examples of changes include:

- content uri format support (i.e. one version of the app support `content://contacts/people/1` the next may support that and `content://contacts/people/john/doe`)
- returned extra content change (i.e. one version of the intent may return with `phone` in the extra while another version may return with `phone` and `address` in the extra.)

Is there an established way of versioning/communicating these kinds of changes for inter-operability/compatibility purposes?

I can think of a few possibilities but not sure which is the best (or if there is a best):

- version the action (i.e. `com.example.v1.SCAN`)
- version the content uri (i.e. `content://contacts/v1/people/john/doe`)
- having a `version` field in the returned extra

I have run into at least one case of intent incompatibility (using zxing library where the extra returned from SCAN action may differ depending on the version of the library/app available.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a version field with a number, it's faster to parcel than a larger string and easier to compare.